# How to bind an unreferenced DLL (like servicelocator/dynamic loading) using Ninject?

Tags: c#, dynamic, dll, binding, ninject

I've been testing Ninject.

Can someone please explain how to bind an unreferenced DLL to a certain Interface.

Here is what I did.

Style: Service Locator
Unreferenced DLL (MyRepository.dll) which implements `IMyRepository`

```
var MyRepo = ServiceLocator.Get<DomainInterfaces.IMyRepository>();
var WorOrderStates = MyRepo.FetchWorkOrderStates();
```

---

Style: Dependency Injection
Referenced DLL (MyRepository.dll) which implements `IMyRepository`

```
IMyRepository service = new CoreServices.MyService(new MyRepository());
var WorOrderStates = service.FetchWorkOrderStates();
```

---

Now. the two styles work perfectly and I'm happy about it, but I don't want my Client Layer knowing my DAL (MyRepository.dll).

Is Dynamic Loading (service Locator) feature supported by Ninject?

Like:

```
var varMyRepository = load_Dynamically_and_get_its_Concrete_type
Kernel.Bind<IMyRepository>.To<>(varMyRepository);
```

===========================================================================================

**Update From Se7en6ix**

Hi, thanks to you **Vinz**, you've shed a light. here's my revised version based on your good answer. although it takes 10ms to load the assembly compared to Activator.CreateInstance, i think it's acceptable.

All i need now is to check for leaks.. Thanks

```
const string dll = "Gasket.Infrastructure.Data.dll";
var MyAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dll).CreateInstance("Infrastructure.Data.Repository", true);
var MyAssemblyType = MyAssembly.GetType();
kernel.Bind<DomainInterfaces.IServiceRepository>().To(MyAssemblyType);
var repo = kernel.Get<DomainInterfaces.IServiceRepository>();
var states = repo.FetchGRStates(); //YESSSSS!
```

Comment: I am curious about your requirement... are you hoping to dynamically switch  your DAL out?

Comment: kind of.... I just want my Infrastructure.Data (DAL) NOT to be referenced by my client layer.

Comment: I'm quite confused with dependency Injection.. I know its good and beneficial... But, if the client layer has reference to both Domain/Core and Infrastructure.DATA (DAL). Why Use COnstructor Injection when a programmer can directly get the methods from the referenced DAL.

Comment: @Se7en6ix: You are creating an object just to get its type when you can directly find the type. Also, you are mandating that the implementing class name SHOULD be "Infrastructure.Data.Repository". This is a constraint from my point of view. But of-course, you implement whichever way works best for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the solution you are looking for but you can load the assembly (using Assembly.Load*()) yourself before Ninject executes so that it can traverse the Types in your dll and find the implementation for IMyRepository. Client Layer still needs to know the dll path or filename.

**EDIT:**

We have to manually find the implementing type and bind it to IDataRepository using ninject. This worked for me:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dllPath);

var dataRepositoryType = typeof(IDataRepository);
var types = assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(dataRepositoryType.IsAssignableFrom).ToList();

// thow error if more than one implementing type

IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<IDataRepository>().To(types[0]);

var repo = kernel.Get<IDataRepository>();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh I see... I tried to load the (DAL)DLL via Activator.CreateInstance. But I get an error binding it using kernel.Bind<Interface>.To<ReturnedObjectFromCreateInstance>();

Comment: @Se7en6ix: You have to bind types and not objects. Please check my edit above.